# Can't bind jQuery selectors to anything but document - Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Super weird problem here. I'm having trouble getting jQuery to bind any selectors except document, inside a .js file.

example code:

```
$(document).click(function () {
 $("#nav_primary").empty();
});
```

when I click anywhere, the nav_primary div empties, as expected, however, when I use this code:

```
$("div").click(function () {
 $("#nav_primary").empty();
});
```

nothing happens when I click. UNLESS I enter it into my console. When I paste the above code into my firebug console, it loads as expected, and clicking anywhere empties out the div as expected.

I know javascript and jquery are both running, as I have this in my js and it logs as expected:

```
console.log("js is running");
if (jQuery) {console.log('jQuery is loaded!');}
```

I've heard there are conflicts with prototype, but I don't think i'm running it. here's my head:

```
<head>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/portfolio.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="(token here)" name="csrf-token" />
  <!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css"> #main {display:table;height:100%} </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src='//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid answer. but did you put your code in `ready` function

e.g.

```
$(function() {

    $("div").click(function () {
        $("#nav_primary").empty();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's it. 18 months of working with jQuery and all i've done is modify and maintain other peoples' functions; i've never started my own environment with this framework before. (also, docs.jquery.com is offline at the moment)

Comment: Glad that's my answer help you. The reason why it's doesn't work is because you defined your function in the head but when jquery try to find the `div` element it's can't find anything, since the browser's parser still in the `head` section it has to parse to the end of `body` or `html` tag first

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").click(function () {
 $("#nav_primary").empty();
});
```

Most likely the div you wanted to attach on was not yet in the DOM when you ran your code (and `$("div")` was just an empty list).

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on("click", "div", function () {
 $("#nav_primary").empty();
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, and your solution worked, but another solution had the answer I was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your DOM and assuming you're putting those events inside `$(function() { });`...

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function () {
    $("#nav_primary").empty();
});
```

Comment: while this worked, another answer had the solution I was looking for. (and no, I didn't put it inside $(function(){}); but neither did this page http://api.jquery.com/empty/  I'm guessing that it's because my function is defined in the head, and the example is defined in the body.

Comment: Ya, `$.empty()` is from jQuery **1.0** so I guess the order of operations wasn't a documentation priority at the time (meaning the purpose of `$(document).ready()` wasn't as mainstream)

Comment: well, lots of functions weren't binding; i couldn't get anything to work, and it's because the dom wasn't built when the handler was created.